# How many sevens?

Tags: mathematics

A retail clerk writes down every whole number from 1 to 123456789 on a sheet of paper.

> How many sevens (7s) did he write down in total?

Comment: Fun fact: if he did this with 12pt writing (_with no space between lines_), and wrote in 20 columns on both sides, the piece of paper would need to be over 8 miles long.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! plz help why? remember that ongoing contest puzzles are not valid here

Comment: On a sheet of paper? A single sheet? I want to see it!

Comment: @RadoslavHristov you might use a magnifying glass

Comment: @Will, how do you know that :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Will is a time traveller. he spent over 3 years writting down those numbers and now he came back to tell us

Comment: I too am curious about the need for "help". I wrote a simple Python script which solved this in a few minutes but that feels like cheating.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan is not cheating if the tag is computer puzzle

Comment: @lois6b That was added later, not by the OP, so we don't really know if it was intended to be a computer puzzle

Comment: @lois6b Thanks for the response. Your interpretation was correct. I haven't been around here for very long and this is the first puzzle I've seen here that could be solved with a program. I also wasn't sure if the OP was using the computer-puzzle tag correctly (I hadn't noticed that it had been added by Beastly Gerbil). It did occur to me that this could be a programming assignment for the OP (I see similar homework questions on [so]).

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan oh nice. The thing is, is OP duty to know if is a valid puzzle (reading the tour or meta). Both ongoing contest or homework activities are cheating and its OP's responsability. I hope he proceeds with nice judgement

Comment: @AyandaAgustoZwane, there are multiple answers... and could you explain why the hurry and the "help please"? is this a puzzle of your invention or is a task you must answer?

Comment: I must assume that this is from a contest, and I will therefore flag this for closure. If it is not, then please say so. Otherwise, this will be closed and possibly deleted.

Comment: To the close-voters: are you sure this is a maths problem rather than a maths puzzle? I suspect there may be a quick, clever, and interesting way of finding the solution, though I haven't found one yet.

Comment: @randal'thor we dont even know if the OP knows how this site works.. he/she just ask again for help even though there is multiple answers

Comment: well thx guys i just found the answer

Comment: @Marius, lois6b,A J, elias, Gerbil, etc

Comment: Was this puzzle from an ongoing contest? Or why did it 'save' you to find the answer? Just curious :-)

Comment: I think you should mark as accepted the answer provided by elias. He answered 3 minutes before me and I did have some wrong calculations at first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer:
(sorry for using dot as a separator for thousands. I'm from Romania, this is how we do it here)

> 96.022.049

Reasoning:

> 1 - 10 => 1.
>  10 - 100 => $9 * 1 + 10 = 19$ (70 to 79 not counting twice for 77 because we already counted that).
>  So this means 1 - 100 we get $20$.
>  100 - 1000 => $9 * 20 + 100 = 280$  (10 times what we had before and all the numbers 700 - 799).
>  So 1 to 1000 we get 300.
>  In the same manner
>  1 - 10000 =>  $4.000$
>  1 - 100000 => $50.000$

Following the same pattern:

> 1 - 100.000.000 => $80.000.000$
>  Now we count the total from 100.000.000 to 120.000.000.
>  We can ignore the leading 1 we end up with 2 times the numbers of 7 
>  between 1 and 10.000.000 which was 7.000.000 so 14.000.000.

Again following the same pattern:

> add the numbers of 7 between 120.000.000 and 123.000.000 which is $3*600.000 = 1.800.000$.

In the same manner we get.

> 123.000.000  - 123.400.000 => $4*50.000 = 200.000$.
>  123.400.000  - 123.450.000 => $5*4.000 = 20.000$.
>  123.450.000  - 123.456.000 => $6*300 = 1.800$.

Now it gets tricky.

> 123.456.000  - 123.456.699 => $7*20 = 140$.
>  123.456.700  - 123.456.789 => $90 + 10 + 9 = 109$ (one 7 in every number - the hundreds, + 10 of them have 2 7's - the tens + 9 for the last digit).

Summing this up we get

> $80.000.000 + 14.000.000 + 1.800.000 + 200.000 + 20.000 + 1.800 + 140 + 109$

Which is

> $96.022.049$

I hope I didn't miss anything.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've missed anything, but you definitely counted some of them more times.

Comment: This overcounts. {10,...,100} indeed have 10 7s in the tens place, but have only 9 7s in the units place -- the other 7 in the units place comes from 7, which you'd counted in your {1,...,10} stage. There is more multiple counting later.

Comment: @elias. I think I missed something and that's why I counted some of them twice. I'm revising this, but at least the approach is good.

Comment: 10-100 actually has only 19 I think, just as RosieF says.

Comment: @elias. Yep you are right. I'm recalculating now. I won't change the approach. Only the digits.

Comment: I've changed the numbers. Can someone please double check it?

Comment: I think you missed some in the 123.456.700 - 123.456.789 step; there are more than 10 with 2 7's, namely everything with 77*, but also everything with 7*7. Therefore it should be 18 7's in the tens instead of 10 7's, giving you the same answer as the others. _Edit:_ I see you fixed it while I was typing.

Comment: OP seems to be confused which one to mark right.

Comment: @AJ v.v yeah ..

Comment: @lois6b, http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38945/next-number-in-the-following-sequence/38946#comment116303_38946

Comment: ...So then what do you use for decimals?

Comment: commas, I suppose

Comment: @Mithrandir. Commas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_point

Comment: @elias nice one! hahahaha I mantain that, is OP's decision hahahah i loled

Answer (score 24):

I might be wrong, as I did all the calculations manually, but as far as I can see, this has a beautiful symmetry, so let me post a solution which uses it:

I would do it by counting it in separate ranges, namely the following:

- 1 to 99999999
  We can actually count it from 0 to 99999999, or even from 00000000 to 99999999 without the answer changing.
  From this latter form it is trivial that all the digits appear the same number of times, and there are a total of 8x100000000 digits (there are 100000000 numbers, each one being 8 digits), so the number of 7s is the tenth of them, that is **80000000**.
- 100000000 to 119999999
  The prefix being either 10 or 11, does not contain any 7s. 20000000 numbers, each with a 7-digit ending, in which every digit appears the same number of times again. That's **14000000** 7s.
- 120000000 to 122999999
  Analogously to the previous ones. 3000000 numbers, 6-digit ending. **1800000** 7s.
- 123000000 to 123399999
  Analogously to the previous ones. 400000 numbers, 5-digit ending. **200000** 7s.
- 123400000 to 123449999
  Analogously to the previous ones. 50000 numbers, 4-digit ending. **20000** 7s.
- 123450000 to 123455999
  Analogously to the previous ones. 6000 numbers, 3-digit ending. **1800** 7s.
- 123456000 to 123456699
  Analogously to the previous ones. 700 numbers, 2-digit ending. **140** 7s.
- 123456700 to 123456769
  A minor trick here. Besides the usual '70 numbers, 1-digit ending'-mantra resulting in **7** 7s, there is another **70** coming from the prefix.
- 123456770 to 123456779
  Like the last one: **1** 7 in the ending, **20** in the prefix, as the prefix itself has 2 7s now.
- 123456780 to 123456789
  The same approach gives **1** in the ending, **10** in the prefix.

In total:

> **96022049** 7s

Answer (score 10):

The answer is:

> 96022049

Because:

> I wrote this code:   (I know its ugly)
>  `int num = 0;
>     for (int i= 1; i<= 123456789 ; i++){
>       if(String.valueOf(i).contains("7")){//if contains at least 1 seven
>         for(int j =0; j < String.valueOf(i).length() ; j++){
>
>             if( String.valueOf(i).charAt(j) ==  ("7").charAt(0) ){// how many 7's inside
>                 num++;
>             }
>         }
>       } 
>     }
>     System.out.println(num);`

Comment: Will that not count numbers like 77 just once?

Comment: true ^^'  i need to modify it heheh

Answer (score 6):

I've just run a program that gives me:

> 96022049

The code used :

> `int count = 0;
>   for(int i=1; i <= 123456789; i++)
>   {
>       QString s = QString::number(i);
>
>       if(s.contains("7"))
>       {
>           int number = s.count(QString::number(7));
>
>           count = count + number; 
>       }
>   }`

Answer (score 6):

Well, the answer is

> 96022049

As wrote the program

> [image]

Comment: congrats A J , but let me ask, *why is this the correct one?* my answer and elias are the same and with more votes and less time to post

Comment: @lois6b This is what surprised me. I didn't expect this.

Comment: @AyandaAgustoZwane I must say there are better answers than mine.

Comment: Why the screenshot and not the code itself?

Comment: It's OPs decision. I'm fine with it, in the worst case, I get my Populist badge...

Comment: @Marius Because there were problem while putting them into spoiler tag. And this took time which is why IAmInPLS beat me.

Comment: It is fine. OP has all the rights to choose the answer he liked the most. Most of us is not here for the reputation scores anyway.

Comment: If you think this is worth a discussion, bring it to Meta. Comments are definitely not the place for this conversation.

Comment: I don't think it's right either that my answer is the accepted one: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42029/how-many-sevens#comment124925_42029

Answer (score 4):

> 96022049

I found this number by using this script :

> `var sevenTotalCount = 0
>
> for (var i = 1; i <= 123456789; i++) {
>   var iStr = i.toString();
>   var sevenCount = (iStr.match(/7/g) || []).length;
>   sevenTotalCount += sevenCount;
> }
>
> console.log(sevenTotalCount);`

Edit: off by one error

Comment: Only less than 123? You might want to include the final number too.

Comment: I posted my test code by mistake =( I fixed it now.

Answer (score 4):

Based on loi6b my version of his program:

> 96022049

Because:

> I wrote this code:
>  
>
>  `class Program
>  {
>    static void Main( string[] args )
>    {
>       long num = 0;
>
>       for (long i= 1; i<= 123456789 ; i++)
>       {
>           if (i.ToString().Contains("7"))
>           {
>               num += i.ToString().Count(f => f == '7');
>           }
>       }
>    }
>  }`

Comment: I guess you were [ninja'd](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42034/25957)!

Comment: HAHAHAH i also finished the execution of the updated program. less elegant tho

Answer (score 3):

How about:

> You know there is one seven in the last position each ten numbers, ten
>  seven in the second last position each 100, ... So:
>   
>  `1) 123456789/10 = 12345678.9 --> 12345679*1 sevens
>  2) 123456789/100 = 1234567.89 --> 1234568*10 sevens
>  3) 123456789/1000 = 123456.789 --> 123457*100 -10 sevens
>  4) 123456789/10000 = 12345.6789 --> 12345*1000 sevens
>  5) 123456789/100000 = 1234.56789 --> 1234*10000 sevens
>  6) 123456789/1000000 = 123.456789 --> 123*100000 sevens
>  7) 123456789/10000000 = 12.3456789 --> 12*1000000 sevens
>  8) 123456789/100000000 = 1.23456789 --> 1*10000000 seven`
>  
>  Note the rounding, if the decimal part is >= 0.7, then you can add a
>  seven. Else only the integer part would count. Note also the $-10$ in $3)$ because ten sevens won't appear in the third last position.
>  
>  Then you add:
>  
>      12345679*1+1234568*10+123457*100-10+12345*1000+1234*10000+123*100000+12*1000000+1*10000000=96022049

Solution:

> There are 96'022'049 sevens

Comment: multiply it by 7 and wonder!

Comment: @elias but... why?

Comment: There are many loosely related reasons behind this, I think. Actually your answer is very close to 1/10+1/10^2+1/10^3+...=1/9 times 123456789, while the solution of the original problem is close to 7/9 times it - this has a more complicated reason. Have you ever wondered, what is the decimal representation of 10/81?

Comment: Since nobody has given constructive criticism yet, and the correct answer has been posted by multiple people for several hours: You say, "there is ... one seven in the second last position each 100 [numbers]". Think about that for a moment. What's the ***one*** number between 1 and 100 that has a 7 in the second-to-last position (i.e., the second-from-the-right; i.e., the $10$s position)? If you haven't had an "Aha! moment" yet: call that number $N$, and look ant $N-1$ and $N+1$.

Comment: @PeregrineRook Aha!... Edited, now I get the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Notice some pattern in it.

```
1        ->0
12       ->1
123      ->22(contain 22 7's in the range of 1 to 123)
1234     ->343
12345    ->4664
123456   ->58985
1234567  ->713307
12345678 ->8367637
123456789->96022049
```

So now as we minus below number(containg number 7's) by above number

```
  1-0                       ->1
  22-1                      ->11
  343-22                    ->321
  4664-343                  ->4321
  58985-4664                ->54321
  713307-58985              ->654322
  8367637-713307            ->7654330
  96022049-8367637          ->87654412
```

They getting some pattern (can say palindromic) but actually they not.

Hope you guys would find out something.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> 96022049

Calculated using the following Python 3 script:

> `count = 0
>  for s in range(123456789+1):
>      count += str(s).count("7")
>  print(count)`

Comment: You're missing many 7s.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Thanks for the feedback. I fixed the program to account for multiple occurrences of numerals in each number.

Comment: you're still missing one, as range(n) goes up to n-1

Answer (score 0):

> **Once.**
>
> The number '7' occurs only once, as with all numbers.

Comment: Yes but the queston is how many sevens did he write down in total. Not how many times he wrote 7.

Comment: He wrote down *one* seven, because there is *only one seven*.

Comment: This is not lateral-thinking +

Comment: OP is new, maybe he doesnt know about lateral thinking tag. he should specify the statement as: how many digits are seven?

Comment: +1 If we can assume the OP meant a computer puzzle and the total number of 7s (and edit the question to suit that assumption) why can't we assume it was lateral thinking?